# What's the format of the debconf config.dat file?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, debconf

debconf has a file at `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` that contains answers to configuration questions. For example,

```
Name: libpam-runtime/profiles
Template: libpam-runtime/profiles
Value: unix, systemd
Owners: libpam-runtime
Variables:
 profile_names = mkhomedir, unix, systemd
 profiles = activate mkhomedir, Unix authentication, Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy
```

What are `Name` and `Template` and why do they always seem to be the same? `Value` and `Owners` seem clear enough. Most of all, what is the `Variables` part for? I thought the whole stanza was describing a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, that stanza is describing a [*Question*](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/blob/master/Debconf/Question.pm), in debconf terminology.

As for `Template`, from [the doc text of the corresponding Perl module](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/blob/76e3a30270e34b5037784f82fa40fcc483dde43a/Debconf/Template.pm#L60):

> When a new template is created, a question is created with the same
>   name as the template. This is to ensure that the template has at least
>   one owner -- the question, and to make life easier for debconf users
>   -- so they don't have to manually register that question.
>
> The owner field, then, is actually used to set the owner of the
>   question.

It's likely that most users of debconf didn't need to create additional questions based on the same template.

To understand the `Variables` part, you need to look up the corresponding template. In this case, `profiles` is a list of choices (see `/var/cache/debconf/templates.dat`):

```
Name: libpam-runtime/profiles
Choices: ${profiles}
Choices-c: ${profile_names}
Description: PAM profiles to enable:
...
```

And from [`man 7 debconf`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html), this is an instance of the `select` variable type:

```
select A choice between one of a number of values. The choices must be specified in
       a  field  named  'Choices'.  Separate  the  possible  values with commas and
       spaces, like this:
         Choices: yes, no, maybe
```

The `Choices-C` field is closely related:

```
DEBCONF_C_VALUES
      If this environment variable is set to 'true', the frontend will display the values
      in Choices-C fields (if present) of select and multiselect  templates  rather  than
      the descriptive values.
```